# Stop animation replaying when switch back to cached views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic in my hybrid app.

I implemented a view listing photos with fadeIn animation effect (using animate.css). It looks good, but every time I switch back to this cached view, all the animations will be replayed, which is annoying. Is there anyway to stop it?

Comment: Can you post your code ?